# Upload index to Algolia via Yahoo FInance API. Cannot access array even though I can console.log

Tags: reactjs, algolia, yahoo-finance, rapidapi

The problem is that I can console.log the array from the useEffect hook, but when I go to access it, it returns an empty array.

I am trying to upload data to my Algolia index.

Here is the current `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchListings = () => {
      api
        .listNasdaq()
        .then((response) => {
          setListings(response.data);
          console.log(response); //I can see the array of data here.
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
    fetchListings();
  }, []);
```

api.js:

```
listNasdaq: () =>
    exchangeApi({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/companies/list-by-exchange",

      transformResponse: [
        function (data) {
          // Do whatever you want to transform the data
          console.log("Transforming Nasdaq Data...");

          const json = JSON.parse(data);

          const stocks = Object.keys(json["results"]);

          const stockNames = stocks.map(
            (stock) =>
              (stock = {
                stock,
                stockName: String(json["results"][stock]["companyName"]),
                symbol: String(json["results"][stock]["symbol"]),
                industry: String(json["results"][stock]["industryOrCategory"]),
              })
          );

          data = {
            stockNames,
          };

          return data;
        },
      ],
    }),
```

Algolia:

```
  nasdaqIndex
    .saveObjects(listings, {
      autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist: true,
    })
    .then(({ objectIDs }) => {
      console.log("algolia stuff", objectIDs);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your map function. Are you injecting the full stock object back into itself (`(stock = { stock, ...`)? What does the final `stock` object look like when you log it? I'm worried that might be confusing Algolia when you go to save the record.

```js
          const stockNames = stocks.map(
            (stock) =>
              (stock = {
                stock,
                stockName: String(json["results"][stock]["companyName"]),
                symbol: String(json["results"][stock]["symbol"]),
                industry: String(json["results"][stock]["industryOrCategory"]),
              })
          );
```

Also, I assume the call to `nasdaqIndex.saveObjects()` occurs in `setListings()`? It looks like some of this code may be missing here.